# Open source project that uses React with Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, frontend, material-ui

Is there any open source project on GitHub that uses React, react-router, etc with Material-UI?

I searched quite a lot and couldn't find one... still, I hope that there is as it would be tremendously helpful to me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check project of material-ui it self.

[Demo](http://www.material-ui.com/#/)

[Source Code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/ccf712c5733508784cd709c18c29059542d6aad1/docs)

It uses React, react-router with Material-UI

Comment: @IvanAsh i hope it solves your problem. Please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you my [Razzle Material UI Styled Example](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example) project.

However react-router is not included by default you can use it easily with this project set-up.